# Silverlight 4: Free Split Button

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, button

I'm looking for free splitbutton control for silverlight.

I've seen this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/06/11/splitbuttoning-hairs-two-fixes-for-my-silverlight-splitbutton-menubutton-implementation-and-true-wpf-support.aspx) however I cannot download it. Its blocked in my firewall.

Do you know any free splitbutton for silverlight?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is available for free in the Silverlight Toolkit.

1. Download the latest Silverlight Toolkit from CodePlex.

   ```
   http://silverlight.codeplex.com/
   ```
2. Download the SplitButton Samples and Project. You may use the SplitButton project to compile your own version of the SplitButton.dll or use the Sample programs to study. (optional)

   ```
   http://dlaa.me/Samples/SplitButton/SplitButton.zip
   ```
3. Add references (right click References) to the Silverlight toolkit and the SplitButton.dll in your Silverlight project.

   ```
   SplitButton.dll
   System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit.dll
   ```
4. Add both namespaces to your XAML, for the Silverlight toolkit and the new SplitButton.

   ```
   xmlns:splitButton="clr-namespace:Delay;assembly=SLTKSplitButton"
   xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit"
   ```
5. Add the Split Button code. This makes one button that drops to three options.

   ```
   <splitButton:SplitButton x:Name='Button1' Content="Open" Click="Button1_Clicked"> 
     <splitButton:SplitButton.ButtonMenuItemsSource>
         <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Open" Click="Button1_Clicked" />
         <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Open read-only" Click="Button1_ClickedRO" />
         <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Open as copy" Click="Button1_ClickedAC" />
     </splitButton:SplitButton.ButtonMenuItemsSource>
   </splitButton:SplitButton>
   ```
6. Add Csharp code for click handlers for main button click or any of the three sub-option clicks.

   ```
   private void Button1_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
     MessageBox.Show("Opening document normally...");
   }

   private void Button1_ClickedRO(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
     MessageBox.Show("Opening document read-only...");
   }

   private void Button1_ClickedAC(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
     MessageBox.Show("Opening document as a copy...");
   }
   ```
7. Give thanks to  David Anson, a Microsoft developer who works with the Silverlight, Windows Phone, and WPF platforms. Twitter: @DavidAns